# Database from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005/2008 still not supporting MARS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-mars

So I'm experiencing the issue described in the title.
I know SQL 2000 doesn't support MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) but my clients have SQL 2005/2008 and some of them are still having problems when I use MARS because their databases came from SQL 2000.

There is any workaround for MARS in this cases?

ps: I'm terrified just thinking of not using MARS

Comment: Check if those databases are in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode and change to 2005/2008. Right click on database in SSMS and Properties->Options.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic That should be the answer.

Comment: I just checked and my client only have 2 options: SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000 (80)
Yes, he have SQL Server 2005 installed on his machine.

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of SQL Server actually running the database is SQL Server 2005? This looks more like it is 2000. Number behind server name, does it start with 8 or 9? You can also check with `SELECT @@Version`.

Comment: My client didn't attach the database from 2000 to 2005 that's why the option was not available. Now it's everything working! Thank you so much for your help!